# mysql_num_rows() error when using include with localhost

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a Problem when including using localhost. lets say that i have mysql query like this, `$strQuery="SELECT employeeName,employeeId FROM employee_tbl where employeeId='$employeeId' "`. Then i Use mysql_num_rows() to make sure that employee with that employeeId exist in my database, but when i use the query it says that `mysql_num_rows expecting 1 to be result` (correct me if im wrong).

It gave me 2 hours headache to fix the problem. First I check the Query, no problem found. Then i Check The Input from HTML input with my var at PHP, nothing wrong. When i cant take the headache anymore i change the Include from localhost to relative path of my app, and IT's WORKED.

i Have no Idea whats wrong. So If you could tell me spesificly it would be nice. Thanks.

As Requested This is My Exact Code :

```
`<?php 
include "localhost/sampleWeb/conf/connection.php";
some code right here
$strQuery="SELECT employeeName,employeeId FROM employee_tbl where employeeId='$employeeId'";
$execQuery=mysql_query($strQuery);
$getData=mysql_num_rows($execQuery)
if ($getData == 0) {
some script done here
} else {
some script done here
}
another code here
?>`
```

*NOTE : the Error have been fixed, but i have no idea why localhost cause the error. Thats why im asking u too shae your knowledge :D

Comment: show us your exact code ? where is `mysql_query` ?

Comment: Also check these if you have time : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php , you will need these as you are using mysql

Answer (score 1):

The error message sounds to me, that you have forgotten to use `mysql_query` first, before using `mysql_num_rows`

```
$strQuery="SELECT employeeName,employeeID FROM employee_tbl where employeeId='$employeeId'";
$result = mysql_query($strQuery);
if(isset($result) {
 $noOfResults = mysql_num_rows($result);
}
```

But please share complete code to identify your problem exactly.

Answer (score 0):

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "database_name");

$query = $mysqli->query("SELECT employeeName,employeeID FROM employee_tbl where employeeId='$employeeId'") or die($mysqli->error);
$count = $query->num_rows();
```

or

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT employeeName,employeeID FROM employee_tbl where employeeId='$employeeId'");
$count = mysql_num_rows($sql);
```

Comment: is it better to use `count()` than `if()` ? or i can still use the `if()` ?

Comment: sure you can use if() statement. That depends on your choice. Personally i store the rows in a variable as it might be needed later